# Avoide swipe right and swipe left into pushed Segue

Tags: xcode, ipad, master-detail

I have a standard MasterDetailApplication for iPad.
From the DetailViewcontroller (if the iPad is in Portrait mode) the Segue "Image View" will be pushed. "Image View" has the size: iPad Full Screen.
With the swipe right or left, the MasterView will appear on the left side of "Image View". How can I avoid this?

Allpication will return to the Master-Detail View if the iPad is in Landscape mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UISplitViewController there is a property to Specify whether the hidden view can be presented and dismissed via a swipe gesture.

The property name is presentsWithGesture

```
   self.splitViewController.presentsWithGesture=NO;
```

Setting this property NO will disable gesture recognizer

Comment: Excellent working fine ...